# Value from @EditorFor disappears when I use AngularJS - MVC asp.net

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Value from @EditorFor disappears when I use AngularJS

In this way is fine, i see value 5 on View (controller set value 5).

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuantityInPack)
```

However when i try

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuantityInPack, new { htmlAttributes = new { ng_model = "QuantityInPack" } })
```

because i need to use this value to count something - it just disappear. Why and how to fix this?

Angular working fine, because when When I typed in this empty field value everything is okay. But it has to be value from controller.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty sure it shows until AngularJS kicks in. your `QuantityInPack` property in the Angular model is missing.

It isn't a good thing to mix ASP.NET MVC Controls with AngularJS.
Use the following by make sure Angular Controller is extracting the value from the server and updating your model.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="QuantityInPack" />
```

Comment: Then how do I retrieve the value of model.QuantityInPack?

Comment: You will need to make a `json` request and populate your model with the response (with QuntityInPack included).

Comment: Ugh it sounds such a difficult :(

Comment: Not so much.. just fire an ajax request to your WebApi matching controller return a model that reflect the desired response and on the Client side assign the response into your angular model. In a Nutshell..